# Redux middleware with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, middleware

I really like the concept of having actions written like this:

```
function signUp(data, callback) { 
return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      type: 'SOME_TYPE',
      url: `/api/account/signup`, 
      method: 'POST',
      data: data

    }
  }
}
```

But for thing like `signUp` I don't want to modify/touch the **store** to get a callback from server

---

In my **React** component I have an action that calls the api through an  action and changes the state.

```
  this.signUp($(form).serialize(), function(data) {  this.setState({response: data});   }.bind(this))
```

and action `signUp` looks like this

```
function signUp(data, callback) { 
 postRequest(
    '/api/account/signup', 
    data, 
    'POST', 
    callback)
}


function postRequest(url, data, method, callback) { 
callback(true); //// just testing  
}
```

As you can see the syntax and the length of code isn't pretty compared to the **first** one

---

**Question**: Is there a way to modify the redux middleware OR have an alternative JSON function (similar to `CALL_API`) to accept callbacks to component without touching the store? I really want to use the `CALL_API` syntax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write middleware to intercept actions and do some work without modifying the store's state.

```
// Action creator    
function signUp(data, callback) { 
  return {
      type: CALL_API
      url: '/api/account/signup', 
      method: 'POST',
      data: data,
      callback: callback
  }
}

// Middleware
const actionInterceptor = store => next => action => {
    if (action.type === CALL_API) {
        postRequest(action.url, action.method, action.data, action.callback);
    }
    else {
        return next(action);
    }
}

...

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(actionInterceptor));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting 'callback undefined'.. Have you tested this code?

Comment: I made an edit to add callback to the action and the way it's used in the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

> I really like the concept of having actions written like this:
>
> `...`
>
> But for thing like signUp I don't want to modify/touch the store to get a callback from server

Ok, but whats the point of using redux for this?

What I understood:
you would like to call `dispatch(signUp(data, callback))` (simplified)

Your signUp actionCreator should look like this:

```
function signUp(data, callback) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    //.. do your stuff with data..
    //.. and call your callback or pass it to another function
  }
}
```

Sorry if misunderstood your problem, please write a comment if something is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks, CALL_API is the type of action I want to have for simple GET/POST requests from components. So "dispatch" doesn't help as it's used to notify the reducer which eventually changes the state/store

Comment: @Fox ok, how is your post related to redux?

Comment: @Fox by design ACTIONS in Redux are related to the state.. You want some other effects.. this is not a problem you can do it, but then its not redux..

Comment: The ACTIONS originate from redux... I am too busy to argue. Thanks anyway